# How to cascade child and parent in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cascade

I set up a relationship b/w two column (primary key and foreign key on unique id)

I am able two change id in parent form and its effect on child table but the problems is it can only change the primary key not another column so they never change and it cause problem for user and report functions. I created the relation with SQL Server 2008 R2's diagram and I use dataset.

I tried to use delete cascade and it works fine and deletes the whole child in all forms but on update I have problem.

Is there any way to update all child columns from a parent table?

Thanks.

Comment: How about using `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on your FK relationship?

Comment: i tried and same problem still exist